# How do I stop a function from running more than once when not needed to?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

So basically when I click "About Me" more than once, the jquery animation stops, knowing that its not suppose to run again.

But when I click "My Portfolio", "Web", "Graphic" and "Others" more than once, the #box1 div just keeps move down and down. You dont see it at first, but once you press "About Me" again, you'll see what happens.

How do I stop this from happening?

Here's a JSFiddle link
https://jsfiddle.net/yg4717a8/1/

Thanks in advance guys :)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var hasSlid = false;
    $('a#hide').click(function () {
        $('#box1').animate({
                'top': '+=155px',
                easing: 'easeInOutCubic',
                opacity: 0
            }, 500,
            function () {
                $('#box1').hide();
            });


        $('#container').show();
        hasSlid = false;
    });
});
```

Comment: You just need a simple flag check, e.g. an `.active` class

Comment: @billybobjones, Where do you want the top of "About Me" to be after it is clicked?  If you click on "About Me" first, it will load behind the menu.  If you click on anything else first, it will load below.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `stop`, to stop previous animations.

```
$('#box1').stop(true, true).animate({
```

> Stop the currently-running animation on the matched elements.

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/yg4717a8/2/